# Hibernate multiple ManyToMany association leads to wrong number of columns error

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, mapping, many-to-many

I have a bit of a complex database structure which I want to explain at first. We have the following tables:

```
Mandant (Id, Name)
Leistungsbereich (Id, Label)
Benutzer (Id, LoginName)
```

Here we have two association tables:

```
Mandant_Leistungsbereich (Id, MandantId, LeistungsbereichId)
Benutzer_Mandant_Leistungsbereich (Id, BenutzerId, MandantLeistungsbereichId)
```

The primary keys are always the 'Id' columns and the foreign keys are obvious I think.

For the first three tables I have the corresponding Domain Java classes that are working with Hibernate.

To get all `Leistungsbereich` items for the `Mandant` I have the following code in my `Mandant` domain class:

```
@JoinTable(
    name = "Mandant_Leistungsbereich",
    joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(
            name = "MandantId"
            )
        },
    inverseJoinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(
            name = "LeistungsbereichId"
        )
    }
)
@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
private Set<Leistungsbereich> leistungsbereiche;
```

When I load a `Mandant` automatically all `Leitungsbereich` items are loaded in the Java Set. Hibernate knows that it has to search in the `Mandant_Leistungsbereich` association table, so this works fine so far.

Now comes the strange part. I also want to achieve the same thing for the `Benutzer` because the `Benutzer` should have a list (or better to say a set) of `Mandant_Leistungsbereich` items.

So I do the same in the `Benutzer` class:

```
@JoinTable(
    name = "Benutzer_Mandant_Leistungsbereich",
    joinColumns = {@JoinColumn( name = "BenutzerId" ) },
    inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn( name = "MandantLeistungsbereichId" ) }
)
@ManyToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
private Set<MandantLeistungsbereich> mandantLeistungsbereiche;
```

But then loading a user the following error gets printed out:

```
org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_71hckf2bhqrp78gom71l6eq38:Benutzer_Mandant_Leistungsbereich [MandantLeistungsbereichId])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (Mandant_Leistungsbereich [MandantId,LeistungsbereichId])
```

I really dont know why hibernate thinks that the `Benutzer_Mandant_Leistungsbereich` table needs two foreign keys for the `Mandant_Leistungsbereich` table. Both in the database and in the hibernate mapping is ALWAYS ONLY an `Id` column as primary key so there is no composite key. Why does hibernate tells me that I need two columns for the foreign key?

Comment: You need a composite primary key, Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510547/hibernate-issue-foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-referenced-pri

Comment: I did not read every detail of the answer but the first statement of the answer is ` ... in order to reference a composite primary key, you need a composite foreign key. `. But I do not have any composite keys in my database. Every table referes to another table with its Id column (one column)