# Hibernate: foreign key partially used as primary key

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, orm, foreign-keys

I have been working for hours trying to solve this problem, which seems quite simple from a database point of view but hard to figure out with hibernate.

I have got two tables: VehicleCategory, and Vehicle.

A Vehicle has one VehicleCategory, so a Vehicule references a VehiculeCategory using a foreign key.

**VehicleCategory**:

- String attr1
- String attr2
- Integer attr3
- String attr4
- PRIMARY KEY (attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4)

**Vehicle**

- String name
- String attr1
- String attr2
- Integer attr3
- String attr4
- FOREIGN KEY (attr1, attr2, attr3, attr4) REFERENCES VehicleCategory
- PRIMARY KEY (name, attr1, attr2, attr3)

Here is my point: I **do not want** to use attr4 for my primary key, but I want to use the other foreign attributes in my primary key.

This is the mapping I did:

```
<class name="Vehicle" table="vehicle">
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="name" column="name"/>
        <key-many-to-one name="vehiclecategory" class="VehicleCategory">
            <column name="attr1" not-null="true" />
            <column name="attr2" not-null="true" />
            <column name="attr3" not-null="true" />
        </key-many-to-one> 
    </composite-id>

    <many-to-one name="vehiclecategory" class="VehicleCategory" fetch="select" insert="false" update="false" >
        <column name="attr1" not-null="true" />
        <column name="attr2" not-null="true" />
        <column name="attr3" not-null="true" />
        <column name="attr4" not-null="true" />
    </many-to-one>
</class>
```

I get the following exception:

```
 Foreign key (FK_s94md9vv63hrpwhyaw4rfxec5:vehicle [attr1,attr2,attr3])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (vehicle_category [attr4,attr1,attr2,attr3])
```

I understand what this exception means. But I do not see why I get it because, from my point of view, I did reference the 4-columns primary key in my foreign key, and only used 3 in my Vehicule primary key.

I am using Hibernate 4.3.6

Thank you for your help !

Comment: I'm not sure if you get the point of using a primary key,

Comment: Why can you use a surogate key?

Comment: Here is a good example:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510547/hibernate-issue-foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-referenced-pri

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I read the link you provided but I cannot figure out how it can help me. I will probably try to use a surrogate key, despite the fact that I usually prefer natural keys.

Comment: The Surogate key is the best way to generate primary key.