# HIbernate Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key Error

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I have these two tables in my database:

```
CREATE TABLE classroom_trainee (
  id           BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  trainee_id   BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  classroom_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  completed    BOOLEAN,
  notes        VARCHAR(255),
  result       INT(3),
  feedback     BOOLEAN             DEFAULT 0,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (trainee_id)
  REFERENCES user (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (classroom_id)
  REFERENCES classroom (id)
);

CREATE TABLE trainee_presence (
  id                   BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  classroom_trainee_id BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
  day                  INT(2) NOT NULL,
  presence             BOOLEAN,
  notes                VARCHAR(255),
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (classroom_trainee_id)
  REFERENCES classroom_trainee (id)
);
```

and this is the Entities that I have:

UserEntity.java:

```
.... 

public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "manager_id")
    private UserEntity manager;

    @Column(name = "email", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String email;

    @Column(name = "forename")
    private String forename;

    @Column(name = "surname")
    private String surname;

...
```

ClassroomTraineeEntity.java

```
....

public class ClassroomTraineeEntity {

.....

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="trainee_id")
    private UserEntity trainee;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="classroom_id")
    private ClassroomEntity classroom;
....
```

TraineePresenceEntity.java

```
....
public class TraineePresenceEntity {

.......

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="classroom_trainee_id")
    private ClassroomTraineeEntity classroomTrainee;

    @Column(name = "day")
    private Integer day;

    @Column(name = "presence")
    private Boolean presence;
...
```

When in TraineePresenceEntity I use

```
@Column(name="classroom_trainee_id")
private Integer classroomTraineeId;
```

It all works fine and dandy, but with a ClassroomTraineeEntity object I get this exception:

Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FKn85t08ggb5n6ail459koe0sm8:trainee_presence [classroom_trainee_id])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (classroom_trainee [classroom_id,trainee_id])

Anyone knows how I can solve this problem?

Comment: Could you please add your UserEntity mapping

Comment: @Mr.Stef added it to the question. Is there something specific that you want to see about it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510547/hibernate-issue-foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-referenced-pri

Comment: @SunilSinare but I don't have a composite key.

Comment: do you  get this while loading or persisting?

Comment: @Mr.Stef not sure what you mean but it compiles and only throws an error when I'm trying to log in into the system.