# Transform a composite id into a simple id Entity Hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate

I'm working with Java 1.7, JBOSS EAP 6.4, hibernate jpa 2.0 and database oracle.

I'm trying to modify the composite id of an entity into a simple id.

Original Classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO_BAR")
@IdClass(FooBarId.class)
public class FooBar{
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "COD_FOO", 
            updatable = false, 
            insertable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Foo foo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
            name = "COD_BAR", 
            updatable = false, 
            insertable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Bar bar;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COD_FOO")
    private String codFoo;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "COD_BAR")
    private String codBar;
    //getter and setter
}

public class FooBarId implements Serializable {
    private String codFoo;
    private String codBar;

    public String getCodFoo() {
        return codFoo;
    }

    public void setCodFoo(String codFoo) {
        this.codFoo = codFoo;
    }

    public String getCodBar() {
        return codBar;
    }

    public void setCodBar(String codBar) {
        this.codBar = codBar;
    }
}
```

New Classes

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "FOO_BAR")
    public class FooBar{
        @Id
        private Long Id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(
                name = "COD_FOO", 
                updatable = false, 
                insertable = false)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Foo foo;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(
                name = "COD_BAR", 
                updatable = false, 
                insertable = false)
        @JsonIgnore
        private Bar bar;

        @Column(name = "COD_FOO")
        private String codFoo;

        @Column(name = "COD_BAR")
        private String codBar;
        //getter and setter
    }

@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO_BAR_OTHER")
public class FooBarOther{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "DATA")
    private String data;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(
           name = "ID_FOO_BAR", 
           referencedColumnName = "ID",
           insertable = false, 
           updatable = false)
    private FooBar fooBar;
}
```

No problems in the build phase.
In the deploy phase i have the following error:

```
 [PersistenceUnit: PersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: PersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK_ljn0q2iefn1qh0dutifext8fj:FOO_BAR_OTHER [ID_FOO_BAR])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (FOO_BAR [COD_FOO,COD_BAR])"}}
```

something saved the composite key and I can't delete it.

I tried to create a new class FooBar2 with same table FOO_BAR, same error.

I tried to create a class FooBar2 with only Id and same table, same error.

I tried to drop all database constraint, same error.

The only thing that worked was creating a new copy table of the original FOO_BAR2.

How can I fix the problem using the original table?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510547/hibernate-issue-foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-referenced-pri

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate Issue : Foreign key must have same number of columns as referenced primary key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510547/hibernate-issue-foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-referenced-pri)