Foreign key must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key with Map<String, Object>
I have class User:
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User extends HibernatePersistentObject implements Serializable

in which I am trying to get preferences for user:
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "preferences", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "NAME")
    @Column(name = "VAL")
    private Map<String, Preference> preferences;

in Preference class I have:
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "preferences_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "preferences_seq", sequenceName = "preferences_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    @Column(name = "PREFERENCES_ID")
    private int preferenceId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "VAL")
    private String val;

and I am getting an exception:
org.hibernate.MappingException: Foreign key (FK7ar0ym10trw4wvrrermbpcm2l:preferences [preferences_PREFERENCES_ID])) must have same number of columns as the referenced primary key (preferences [user_id,NAME])
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:148)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.ForeignKey.alignColumns(ForeignKey.java:130)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.secondPassCompileForeignKeys(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1914)

How can I fix it? And what's even wrong here? I have separate @Id for these two tables. One is preferenceId and second is userId.

Look at this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14510547/hibernate-issue-foreign-key-must-have-same-number-of-columns-as-referenced-pri

In addition to above comment, can I suggest you to 1. use Wrapper Integer as identifier instead of a primitive one, 2. For complex object types avoid using @ElementCollection(in 1User: N Preferences) it should be @OneToMany 3. Try to avoid FetchType.EAGER at OneToMany side
